# How to find TLS segments of the current thread on linux amd64?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linker, garbage-collection, runtime

I'm looking for a way to find out the memory addresses of TLS segments for the current thread on linux, amd64. Bonus point for a solution that works on OSX.

Looked into various language runtime or GC (like boehm), but couldn't go through the multiple layer of abstractions to support all kind of systems so far. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you have a look at the solution Martin and I came up with in [druntime](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/4bcd672b320c3869b6ee4eeec0ece42826ab931e/src/rt/sections_elf_shared.d)?

What we do there boils down to scanning the segments in the corresponding `dl_phdr_info` (obtained by looking for the correct one using `dl_iterate_phdr`) for the segment with type `PT_TLS`, and storing its module id and size.

You can then get the start of the address range on the current thread by calling `__tls_get_addr` for offset 0 and the module id (there is an offset on some archs), and the end by simply adding the size you determined to that. If you do not need to support shared libraries, you can also simply use `fs`/`gs` on x86 for that (might be required if you want to link a static executable).

---

This works for Linux and FreeBSD (and probably other ELF platforms), but not OS X. There, the best I could come up with so far is this:

```
void _d_dyld_getTLSRange(void* arbitraryTLSSymbol, void** start, size_t* size) {
    dyld_enumerate_tlv_storage(
        ^(enum dyld_tlv_states state, const dyld_tlv_info *info) {
            assert(state == dyld_tlv_state_allocated);
            if (info->tlv_addr <= arbitraryTLSSymbol &&
                arbitraryTLSSymbol < (info->tlv_addr + info->tlv_size)
            ) {
                // Found the range we are looking for.
                *start = info->tlv_addr;
                *size = info->tlv_size;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The naive implementation currently used in LDC's druntime does not quite handle shared libraries, though, and `dyld_enumerate_tlv_storage` is from `dyld_priv.h`, which might or might not be a problem for App Store publishing.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the thread-specific segment is set up via `arch_prtcl(ARCH_SET_FS, <addr>)` call. You can find out what it was set to in the current thread via `arch_prctl(ARCH_GET_FS, ...)`.

> Bonus point for a solution that works on OSX.

OSX is a completely different OS, and uses completely different mechanism for its TLS support.

Comment: That going to tell me where a symbol is, not where the segment start and ends. Also, there is most likely more then one segment when dynamically loaded libraries gets in the fight.